# Bash function not returning value to the script while running through cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a main script that calls a function , which is written in another file.I have sourced this file inside the main script. When I run this main script using cron, then the function does not return any value. Whereas if i run the same main script in console , the function returns value and prints on console.

Below is my main script.

```
source /home/employee/conf/myConf.cfg $0
load_dte=`fnGetDate dir1 dir2/*`
fnLog "load_dte $load_dte"
```

And configuration file that contains the function:

```
function fnGetDate(){
x="2016-06-21"
echo "$x"
}
```

When  this main script is scheduled via cron :
Output is :

`load_dte`

Whithout cron output:

`load_dte 2016-06-21`

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: 
Below is the full codebase:

$1 $2 are the hdfs locations/tmp/hdfs/loc1 and /tmp/hdfs/loc2
main script:

```
#/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

       dirname=$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )
    source `echo ${dirname%/*}`/conf/lib.cfg $
        fnGetScriptPath $0
        fnCreateLogFile ${0}
        fnMain(){
                TBL_BUS="$1"
                TBL_ENT="$2"
                load_dte=fnGetDate "/tmp/hdfs/loc1" "/tmp/hdfs/loc2*" ""
                echo load_dte $load_dte
                fnLog "load_dte $load_dte" "$C_INFO"
        }
                fnMain $1 $2
```

Below is the config file:

```
SCRIPT_NAME="$1"
CURRENT_DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

C_INFO=0
C_SUCCESS=1
C_DEBUG=2
C_WARN=3
C_ERROR=4
LOG_STATUS=(INFO SUCCESS DEBUG WARN ERROR)
function fnCreateLogFile(){
        fnGetScriptPath $1
        FILE=`basename $1`
        LOGDIR=$root_dir/logs
        LOGFILE=${LOGDIR}/${FILE/'.sh'/''}_${CURRENT_DATE}.log
        if [[ ! -d $LOGDIR ]]; then
                mkdir -p $LOGDIR
                fnLog "Creating log dir: $LOGDIR" $C_SUCCESS
         else
                fnLog "Log file : $(cd `dirname $LOGFILE` && pwd)/$FILENAME" "$C_INFO"
        fi
}
function fnGetScriptPath(){

        script_name=`basename $1`
        script_base_name=`echo $script_name | cut -d'.' -f1`

        dir_name=`dirname $1`

        if [[ $dir_name == "."  ]];then
                work_dir=`pwd`
                root_dir=`pwd | awk  'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS = "/"} {$NF="";print}' | sed 's/.$//'`
        else
                work_dir=$dir_name
                root_dir=`echo $dir_name | awk  'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS = "/"} {$NF="";print}' | sed 's/.$//'`
        fi

}

function fnLog() {
        echo `date +"%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S"` $1
        echo `date +"%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S"` $1 >> $LOGFILE
        if [[ $2 -eq 1 || $2 -eq 2 ]]; then MSG_ACCUM="$MSG_ACCUM \\n $1" ;fi
}


    function fnGetDate(){
            HDFS_SRC=$1
            HDFS_TGT=$2
            SKIP=${3:-"0"}
            for X in ${!HDFS_SRC[*]}
            do
                    #echo "comm -23 <(hadoop fs -ls ${HDFS_SRC[X] } | awk -F'/' '{match(\$NF, \"[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\", v)}{print v[0]}' | sort) <( hadoop fs -ls $HDFS_TGT | awk -F'/' '{match(\$NF, \"[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\", v)}{print v[0]}'"
                    HDFS=("${HDFS[@]}" "`comm -23 <(hadoop fs -ls ${HDFS_SRC[X] } | awk -F'/' '{match($NF, "[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+", v)}{print v[0]}' | sort) <( hadoop fs -ls $HDFS_TGT | awk -F'/' '{match($NF, "[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+", v)}{print v[0]}' | sort ) | grep "^[0-9]"`")
            done

            if [[ $value == "" ]];then
                    DATE=( $(
                    for x in "${HDFS[@]}"
                    do
                            echo "$x"
                    done | sort | uniq) )
                    echo ${DATE[$SKIP]}
            else
                    DATE=( $(
                    for f in ${HDFS[@]}
                    do
                            if [[ "$f" > "$value" || "$f" == "$value" ]];then
                                    echo "$f"
                            fi
                    done | sort | uniq) )
                    echo "${DATE[$SKIP]}"
            fi
    }
```

Comment: cron scripts run with the working directory set to the home directory of the userID running the script. that means your dir1/dir2 stuff is effectively running as `~/dir1 ~/dir2/*`. You sure those exist in the user's home dir?

Comment: @MarcB Those directories don't actually do anything if you read the script.

Comment: `$0` is likely to be problematic using cron.

Comment: Does you main script start with the `#!/bin/bash` shebang line?

Comment: yes It starts with #!/bin/bash

Comment: I tried removing $0 and provided the script name instead. But same error.